# Clear Activity on close application

Tags: java, android

I have one android application which have Activity Called A is Main Activity and Activity B is Download Activity which downloading in background data from server. I want stop **activity B** on close application.
Thanks

Comment: *I want stop activity B on close application* That happens automatically

Comment: its downloading from server even we exit application, so why I need stop that activity.

Comment: Call finish(); in your onPause method.